# Do I get reputations if I give good answers not only to ask?

Tags: discussion, support

I’m curious to know what is the maximum reputation to be? And if I see a question then I answer correctly to it then I can get reputations?

Comment: You could easily check that by visiting our [help] ... where you may find a special section entitled "Reputation and Moderation"

Comment: If you give low quality answers you may loose reputation too. So you should better concentrate on learning about Islam before giving your opinion or wrong or half answers! Be patient!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, if you provide good answers and the community up-votes you'll gain reputation and privileges on this site. Same as the case with questions.

There are limits to the daily reputations that you gain but there is no cap on the lifetime reputations. [For example.](https://stackexchange.com/leagues/1/alltime/stackoverflow/)

Comment: So if my reputations starts to grow more then this message”We can no longer accepts questions from this account any longer” will be removed and I can ask again new questions?

Comment: @Medi1Saif Ooooo